# Create a dynamic column sourced from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, dynamic

First off, thanks for all the great help I've received thus far here -- invaluable.

I'd like to create a MySQL table that includes a column dynamically generated from a column in another table, but that can also house a column with manually entered values. In other words:

For example, table 1 has a column called "cars" with items acura, ford, honda etc. Sometimes this table is updated with new cars. Say someone inserts "dodge."

What I need is a different table that has a column called "cars" that automatically updates to reflect the list of items in the "cars" column in the other table; however the table should also have a column called "tires" that can accept new values like "pirellis", "michelin" etc.

In other words, this new table should have a column called cars that is always sourced from another table, but should be able to accept matching "tire" values on insertion -- if that makes sense.

Thanks very, very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do that! It's very very bad design.
You need to create a couple of reference tables cars and tires with many-to-many relationship.

```
table cars:
car_id
car_name

table tires:
tire_id
tire_name

connection table car_tire:
tire_id
car_id
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that -- the point is that I want a table that can be updated by end users via AJAXcrud. So this table (let's call it "CarTires") should have the cars and tires columns, but the cars column should be dynamic such that it always uses the data from the original cars table.

Comment: Another option I'd considered is to just have a cron job update the column in the "CarsTires" table with data from the "cars" table in the other column, but I suspect there's a way to do this dynamically within MySQL....

Comment: What? Maybe I didn't explain properly, but really what I need is a table that has a column populated by a view (so that it is dynamically updated based on another table), but also has another column that someone can enter data into.

Comment: So I've made  bit of progress: I have a view that selects the cars column original "cars" table, so that it's live updated as the original table is modified. I have a separate (empty) table for tires that I left joined to the view. Now my only problem is: how do I make the ids in the joined tire table equal the ids in the cars table?

Comment: look. you have two sets: cars and tires, right? say, ford may be equipped with pirellis and michelin as well. from other side, say, pirelli may be set on both ford and dodge. do I understand right then busines login you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Not quite -- Let's say I have a table called Cars. It has a column called "CarModel" that has Ford, Lincoln, etc. It also has other columns including an ID, and other info about the car (the same car model appears in several rows). Now I want to establish a new table that consists of just the CarModel column from the Cars table, that updates dynamically when the Cars table changes (like a VIEW), but also has another column called "tires" into which values can be inserted. So there may be a new CarModel added to the Cars table with a new id, and it should show up in the joined, dynamic table.